# Cannot connect two Viewcontrollers together

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to connect two `View Controllers` in my storyboard with segues. Usually I just had to `control drag` and then connect them and select the segue I wanted. However now I just control drag, then the blue line appears however when I drop it nothing happens. No pop up, no connection. What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should all work the same. Be sure to drag from your view controller to the the **view** you'll transition to. Give the segue an identifier string and then you can transition with performSegueWithIdentifier.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier", sender:self)
```

[image: Creating a segue]

[image: Naming segue]

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot?